# How to keep a data-bound list reverse-sorted

Tags: wpf, sorting, listbox

I have a listbox bound to a collection. I would like the ListBox to always reverse the order of the items. This handler--hooked up to the control's load event--works for the initial load, but not thereafter. Ive tried using the SourceUpdated event but that doesnt seem to work.

How do I maintain a constant active sort?

```
    MyList.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the collection stored that supplies the items for the ListBox?  It should be a collection that supports [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).  The framework provides `ObservableCollection<T>` which you can use.

In the constructor of your ViewModel (or wherever the collection lives), you then get the DefaultView for adding the `SortDescription`.  The `CollectionView` is like a layer on top of your collection, which you can use to sort, group, filter, etc. the items without actually affecting the underlying data source.  The framework creates a default one for you.  To get a reference to it, you can use code similar to the following:

```
        var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Widgets);
        if(collectionView == null)
            return;

        collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

With that in place, you should be able to add items to the `ObservableCollection<T>` and the sort order will be maintained.

Comment: I think we have a bug in our esri control. The layers collection is an ObservableCollection but it's not properly implementing INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: I guess you could try replacing your control with a vanilla ObservableCollection and see if the problem goes away.  If so, then it looks like there could be a problem with your esri control.

Answer (score 0):

If your source collection is a `List<T>` or some other collection that doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, there is no way WPF can detect when an item is added. You need to use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, like `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Also, the items in your collection need to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` so that changes to the items are taken into account